# Flutter Two sided swipe button creation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

In my case, need up and down swipe button in flutter. My UI design should exactly match the attached screen shot. Can anyone help me to achieve this please??

[image]

Comment: Please have a look [Drag a UI element](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/drag-a-widget)!

Comment: @PradipD. Thanks for the hint. It really worked for me.. Really grateful you.